# Error en formularios con JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, formularios, webforms

- Estoy creando un programa que cuando el usuario digite un color sobre los campos de texto, debe darle click al botón "Mostrar Resultados" automáticamente en los botones de arriba, se agregan esos colores a cada botón asignado en los formularios, y al darle click a cualquier botón, el background cambia dependiendo del color asignado.

  pero al hacer todos esos pasos, los botones al darles click, se reinicia el proceso desde 0 y hay que iniciar de nuevo.

  que podría hacer o cambiar para poder mantener los datos de cada botón y no vuelva a su valor de inicio.*

```js
 function form_get(){
  
 data = {
  value1: forms.form_01.value, // FORMULA:  form:name + input:name + value
  value2: forms.form_02.value,
  value3: forms.form_03.value,
 }
/*
 console.log(data.value1); // valor digitado por user en form 01
 console.log(data.value2); // valor digitado por user en form 02
 console.log(data.value3); // valor digitado por user en form 03*/

 document.getElementById('a_hiper').onclick = function(){

  // call btn_1 
  var call01 = document.getElementById('btn_1');
  call01.innerText = data.value1;
  // call01.innerText = forms.form_01.value;

  document.getElementById('btn_1').onclick = function(){
  document.body.style.background = data.value1;
  }

  // call btn_2
  var call02 = document.getElementById('btn_2');
  call02.innerText = data.value2;

  document.getElementById('btn_2').onclick = function(){ 
   document.body.style.background = data.value2;
  }

  // call btn_3
  var call03 = document.getElementById('btn_3');
  call03.innerText = data.value3;

  document.getElementById('btn_3').onclick = function(){ 
   document.body.style.background = data.value3;
  }




 }
}
```

```html
<!-- Start Forms -->
 <form  name="forms" id="forms_buttons">

  <!-- <label for="form_one"> -->
  <!-- forms -->
  <input type="text" name="form_01" value="">
  <input type="text" name="form_02" value="">
  <input type="text" name="form_03" value=""><br>
 
  <!-- buttons -->
  <button id="btn_1">1</button>
  <button id="btn_2">2</button>
  <button id="btn_3">3</button>

 </form>

 <button id="a_hiper" onclick="javascript:form_get()">Mostrar Resultados</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> que podría hacer o cambiar para poder mantener los datos de cada botón y no vuelva a su valor de inicio.*

Lo que te está pasando es una redirección, esto ocurre cuando no le asignas el atributo `type` a los botones dentro de un `<form>`, así que por defecto toman el valor de `type="submit"`.

Simplemente, asigna cada `<button>` que no quieres que redireccione el atributo `type` de la siguiente manera:

```
<button type="button" id="btn_1">1</button>
<button type="button" id="btn_2">2</button>
<button type="button" id="btn_3">3</button>
```

```js
 function form_get(){
  
 data = {
  value1: forms.form_01.value, // FORMULA:  form:name + input:name + value
  value2: forms.form_02.value,
  value3: forms.form_03.value,
 }
/*
 console.log(data.value1); // valor digitado por user en form 01
 console.log(data.value2); // valor digitado por user en form 02
 console.log(data.value3); // valor digitado por user en form 03*/

 document.getElementById('a_hiper').onclick = function(){

  // call btn_1 
  var call01 = document.getElementById('btn_1');
  call01.innerText = data.value1;
  // call01.innerText = forms.form_01.value;

  document.getElementById('btn_1').onclick = function(){
  document.body.style.background = data.value1;
  }

  // call btn_2
  var call02 = document.getElementById('btn_2');
  call02.innerText = data.value2;

  document.getElementById('btn_2').onclick = function(){ 
   document.body.style.background = data.value2;
  }

  // call btn_3
  var call03 = document.getElementById('btn_3');
  call03.innerText = data.value3;

  document.getElementById('btn_3').onclick = function(){ 
   document.body.style.background = data.value3;
  }




 }
}
```

```html
<!-- Start Forms -->
 <form  name="forms" id="forms_buttons">

  <!-- <label for="form_one"> -->
  <!-- forms -->
  <input type="text" name="form_01" value="">
  <input type="text" name="form_02" value="">
  <input type="text" name="form_03" value=""><br>
 
  <!-- buttons -->
  <button type="button" id="btn_1">1</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn_2">2</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn_3">3</button>

 </form>

 <button id="a_hiper" onclick="javascript:form_get()">Mostrar Resultados</a>
```